# Jetpack Compose Row item height fillMaxHeight does not work with aspect ratio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I am trying to build the following layout:

[image]

I have the following code so far:

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        //First Row
        WidgetComposed(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp),
            bgColor = Color.Red,
            widgetName = "Widget 1"
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

        // Second Row
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
            WidgetComposed(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.6f)
                    .aspectRatio(2f / 3f, true),
                bgColor = Color.Green,
                widgetName = "Widget 2 (2:3)"
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()) {
                WidgetComposed(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1f),
                    bgColor = Color.Blue,
                    widgetName = "Widget 3"
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                WidgetComposed(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1f),
                    bgColor = Color.Cyan,
                    widgetName = "Widget 4"
                )
            }
        }
```

It gives me this:

[image]

The column with Widget 3 and 4 does not fill the height of the parent row. If I put hardcoded height value it works.

Aspect ration and 60% width is important to keep for Widget 2.

WidgetCompose is just a card and a box:

```
@Composable
fun WidgetComposed(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, bgColor: Color, widgetName: String) {
    Card(modifier = modifier, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), backgroundColor = bgColor) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text(text = widgetName)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the column with Widget 3 and 4 automatically fill the available height?
Preferably without using .onGloballyPositioned modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        WidgetComposed(
            Modifier
                .weight(0.6f)
                .aspectRatio(2f / 3f, true),
           //...
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp).fillMaxHeight())

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.4f)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
           //..
        }

   }
```

[image]